# Make two layers in a material/on a Gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine, render

I was wondering if it is possible two make a material which has two layers. That is, everything of the image in the foreground should be visible. However in the places in which it is transparent or in case it isn't filling up the whole plane/Gameobject the background image should be visible.

Workaround:
This includes setting two materials two a plane and rendering the one in the foreground transparent and the one in the background normal. However, the Unity shows me the following warning:
[image]

I assume then it is perfomance costing. Not to mention, I would apply this solution to 40 planes in my scene.

Is there a way to create a submesh for that or should I not use this solution at all?

Possible solution:
Adding creating a mesh for this solution in blender. I think that could be the solution. Nonetheless, I would prefer a different solution since it would cost me a lot of work

Comment: what is the 'background image' in this scenario? Other objects in the scene? Or the orange layer in this image? E.g., if the gray is transparent, what exactly do you expect to see showing through?

Comment: In the background there should be a color (e.g., green, red, orange, black) That said, it should be on the same level/plane

Comment: I'm not an expert so I can't answer directly, but I've seen where you can write a custom shader using multiple channels (RGBA) in a texture to do different things with a single image. You could probably make a custom shader that takes in a 'background color' that gets substituted where the alpha channel is a certain value. [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/creating-a-shader-with-colour-channels.308326/) is similar to what I mean. Though I heard the shader stuff changed in Unity; I haven't tried it in a while.

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/176045/add-single-color-background-to-texture-using-shader)?

Comment: @ps2goat Could you show me how to write this in code/in a .shader file? (I don't have any knowledge in this area)

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience there, either. @derHugo's link looks like what I was thinking of, except you just need to look for your gray color and replace it.

Comment: @ps2goat Is it in that case possible to also change the background color during runtime?

Comment: If it is in the shader you can simply change the according color value on runtime yes

Comment: @derHugo  So I copied the code for the shader from the link but how can I set the values now. Sorry, if I bother both of you with my simple questions.

Comment: I don't know exactly but probably via [`Material.SetColor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetColor.html)

Comment: I used a different solution. Still, thank you for your time and effort. If you post an answer I would accept it

Answer (score 0):

An answer to this question can be found on:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/make-two-layers-of-materials.1093474/#post-7042285

However, the answer in the comments is equally valid and might furthermore be connected to less effort.